# nexus repo path change

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus, nexus3

I have a repository in nexus as release. We generate artifacts using jenkins and maven and the artifacts live and staging both get deployed to release --> com --> content  folder. What i want is that live artifacts should go in release --> com --> content --> live folder and for staging release --> com --> content --> staging folder. I have created live and staging folders .  But i dont know how where to change the path so that  artifacts get into the proper respective folders as required . I have checked pom and setting.xml files but dont get where to make path changes .  My basic requirement is to know where to make path changes if we want the artifacts / war files to be placed in newly created folders.

Comment: Which version of Nexus do you use? Really want to use staging?

Comment: staging is just artifact name...nexus version is 2.14.15

Answer (score 0):

The paths are determined by the groupId. If the groupId is e.g. `com.content.staging`, then the resulting artifact goes to the subfolder `com/content/staging`.